# Find the measure of segment $ED$ in the triangle below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

> Let there be a $\triangle ABC$, such that $AB = 5$, $BC = 6$, and $AC = 4$. The bisectors of angles $B$ and $C$ intersect at point $I$. Draw a parallel to $BC$ through $I$, intersecting $AC$ and $AB$ at $E$ and $D$, respectively. What is the value of $ED$?
> <sub>(Ans:$\frac{18}{5}$)</sub>

I tried as follows.

[image]

$$\frac{5}{AK} = \frac{6}{4-AK} \implies 20-5AK = 6AK \therefore AK = \frac{20}{11} \implies CK = \frac{24}{11}$$

$$\frac{4}{AL} = \frac{6}{5-AL} \implies 20-4AL = 6AL \therefore AL = AL = 2 \implies BL = 3$$

$$\triangle ADE \sim \triangle ACB: \frac{DE}{6}=\frac{AE}{5}=\frac{AD}{4}\tag I$$

$$\triangle AED: \frac{AE}{AD} = \frac{EI}{DI}$$

from $(I)$, $$\frac{EI}{DI} = \frac{5}{4}$$

Comment: FYI, a couple of minor inconsistencies are that, based on the problem description, the point $i$ in the diagram should be $I$ instead, plus $E$ and $D$ are switched around. Also, I believe the "with" in "... intersecting $AC$ with $AB$ at ..." should be "and" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't offhand know how to finish using what you've done. Instead, here's a different method. As indicated in the diagram below, add the line $IF$, and the perpendicular line from $BC$ that goes through $A$, with it crossing $ED$ at $M$ and $BC$ at $N$. Let $\lvert IF\rvert = r$ (so $\lvert MN\rvert = r$ also) and $\lvert AM\rvert = h$.

[image: OP diagram with a few extra lines, line lengths and points added]

The [incircle radius relation to the triangle area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Relation_to_area_of_the_triangle), using that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the side lengths of $\triangle ABC$, is

$$\Delta = sr, \;\;\; s = \frac{a+b+c}{2} = \frac{15}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Using $BC$ as the base, with the one-half base length times the height (i.e., $\lvert AN\rvert$) triangle area formula, we get

$$sr = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)6(r + h) \;\;\to\;\; r + h = \frac{sr}{3} \;\;\to\;\; h = \frac{(s - 3)r}{3} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $DE \parallel BC$, then $\triangle ADE \sim \triangle ACB$ so, using \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A}, gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert ED\rvert}{\lvert BC\rvert} & = \frac{\lvert AM\rvert}{\lvert AN\rvert} \\
\frac{\lvert ED\rvert}{6} & = \frac{\frac{(s-3)r}{3}}{\frac{sr}{3}} \\
\lvert ED\rvert & = \frac{6(s-3)}{s} \\
\lvert ED\rvert & = \frac{18}{5}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Comment: I appreciate the help. To use my development I would need to demonstrate that $EI=EA=AL = 2;$

Comment: @petaarantes You're welcome. However, I'm a bit confused with your statement about demonstrating that $EI = EA = AL = 2$ since, for example, it seems $EA \gt AL$.

Comment: I spelled it wrong. It would be $EI=IA =AL$

Comment: I posted another solution...

Answer (score 1):

$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle  AED \implies \dfrac{ED}{BC}  =\dfrac{r}{H}\\.
S_{\triangle ABC}=S=p.r=\dfrac{(AB+BC+AC)}{2}.r(I)\\
S=S_{\triangle AFC}+S_{\triangle ABF}=\dfrac{1}{2}H(AB+AC)(II)\\
(I)=(II): \dfrac{r}{H}=\dfrac{AB+AC}{AB+BC+AC}\implies \dfrac{ED}{BC}=\dfrac{AB+AC}{AB+BC+AC}\\
\therefore ED=\dfrac{BC(AB+AC)}{AB+BC+AC}=\dfrac{6(5+4)}{4+5+6}=\boxed{\dfrac{18}{5}}$

(Solution by ElManco)

[image]